# How to do sign in with promises after passport.authenticate with social services. KeystoneJS + Passport

Tags: authentication, express, mongoose, keystonejs, passport.js

In addition to [my question in repository](https://github.com/JedWatson/sydjs-site/issues/109) I need to publish it here, may be somebody will help me, i'll appreciate it.

I need to get help with unblocking code in my app.

I have couple services, which after getting callback store user information in session and redirect to page called /auth/confirm/.

Here is the example of twitter auth, works perfectly for me.

```
const keystone = require('keystone');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportTwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
const User = keystone.list('User');

const credentials = {
    consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL,
    includeEmail: true
};

exports.authenticateUser = function(req, res, next) {

    const redirect = '/auth/confirm';

    const twitterStrategy = new passportTwitterStrategy(credentials, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        done(null, {
            accessToken: accessToken,
            refreshToken: refreshToken,
            profile: profile
        });
    });

    // Pass through authentication to passport
    passport.use(twitterStrategy);

    // Save user data once returning from Twitter
    if (req.query.hasOwnProperty('cb')) {

        passport.authenticate('twitter', { session: false }, function(err, data, info) {

            if (err || !data) {
                return res.redirect('/signin');
            }

            const name = data.profile && data.profile.displayName ? data.profile.displayName.split(' ') : [];

            req.session.auth = {
                type: 'twitter',

                name: {
                    first: name.length ? name[0] : '',
                    last: name.length > 1 ? name[1] : ''
                },

                email: data.profile._json.email,

                profileId: data.profile.id,

                username: data.profile.username,

                avatar: data.profile._json.profile_image_url.replace('_normal', ''),

                accessToken: data.accessToken,
                refreshToken: data.refreshToken
            };

            return res.redirect(redirect);

        })(req, res, next);

        // Perform initial authentication request to Twitter
    } else {
        passport.authenticate('twitter')(req, res, next);
    }
};
```

And now we store twitter user in req.session.auth if we get access from user. But now I have a big problem. Mongoose User model works async too as I know and when I try to check existing user by twitter profileID I can't get proper result because it goes to first .then callback and doesn't wait for checking result. I wan't to make this asynchronous but avoiding async library, because it's too large to me for one feature. I prefer to use native Promises which come in at Node new versions. I'm not sure in this all and don't know how to make it with best performance and very expect, that somebody will help me with it. Anyway - thanks for reading...

```
const keystone = require('keystone');
const User = keystone.list('User');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    const locals = res.locals;

    locals.authUser = req.session.auth;

    // Set existing user if already logged in
    locals.existingUser = req.user || false;

    // Reject request if no auth data is stored in session
    if (!locals.authUser) {
        console.log('[auth.confirm] - No auth data detected, redirecting to signin.');
        console.log('------------------------------------------------------------');
        return res.redirect('/');
    }

    const authenticateUser = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (locals.existingUser) resolve(true);
        console.log('[auth.confirm] - Searching for existing users via [' + locals.authUser.type + '] profile id...');
        console.log('------------------------------------------------------------');
        User.model.findOne()
            .where('services.' + locals.authUser.type + '.profileId', locals.authUser.profileId)
            .exec((err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('[auth.confirm] - Error finding existing user via profile id.', err);
                    console.log('------------------------------------------------------------');
                    reject(err);
                }
                if (user) {
                    console.log('[auth.confirm] - Found existing user via [' + locals.authUser.type + '] profile id...');
                    console.log('------------------------------------------------------------');
                    locals.existingUser = user;
                    resolve(true);
                }
                resolve(false);
            });
    });

    authenticateUser
        .then(result => {
            if (result) return result;
            User.model.findOne()
                .where('email', locals.authUser.email)
                .exec((err, user) => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    if (user) {
                        locals.existingUser = user;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
        })
        .then(result => {
            if (result) return result;

            if (locals.existingUser) {
                const userData = {
                    email: locals.authUser.email,
                    services: locals.existingUser.services || {}
                };

                userData.services[locals.authUser.type] = {
                    isConfigured: true,
                    profileId: locals.authUser.profileId,
                    username: locals.authUser.username,
                    avatar: locals.authUser.avatar,
                    accessToken: locals.authUser.accessToken,
                    refreshToken: locals.authUser.refreshToken
                };

                locals.existingUser.set(userData);

                locals.existingUser.save(err => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    return true;
                });

            } else {

                const userData = {
                    name: {
                        first: locals.authUser.name.first,
                        last: locals.authUser.name.last
                    },
                    email: locals.authUser.email,
                    password: Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8),
                    services: {}
                };

                userData.services[locals.authUser.type] = {
                    isConfigured: true,
                    profileId: locals.authUser.profileId,
                    username: locals.authUser.username,
                    avatar: locals.authUser.avatar,
                    accessToken: locals.authUser.accessToken,
                    refreshToken: locals.authUser.refreshToken
                };

                locals.existingUser = new User.model(userData);
                locals.existingUser.save(err => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    return true;
                });
            }
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log('[auth.confirm] - Signing in user...');
            console.log('------------------------------------------------------------');

            const onSuccess = user => {
                console.log('[auth.confirm] - Successfully signed in.');
                console.log('------------------------------------------------------------');
                return res.redirect(req.cookies.target || '/keystone');
            };

            const onFail = err => {
                console.log('[auth.confirm] - Failed signing in.', err);
                console.log('------------------------------------------------------------');
                if (err) throw err;
                return res.redirect('/');
            };

            keystone.session.signin(String(locals.existingUser._id), req, res, onSuccess, onFail);
        });

    return authenticateUser;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment my code is as below. It's working and async, but anyway I will very happy to get somebody's review.

```
const keystone = require('keystone');
const User = keystone.list('User');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    const authUser = req.session.auth;

    // Reject request if no auth data is stored in session
    if (!authUser) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }

    // Set existing user if already logged in
    if (req.user) return doSignIn(req.user);

    User.model.findOne()
        .where('services.' + authUser.type + '.profileId', authUser.profileId)
        .exec()
        .then(user => {
            if (user) return doSignIn(user);
            User.model.findOne()
                .where('email', authUser.email)
                .exec()
                .then(user => {
                    return createOrUpdateUser(user);
                }, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                });
        }, err => {
            throw err;
        });


    function doSignIn(user) {

        const onSuccess = user => {
            return res.redirect(req.cookies.target || '/keystone');
        };

        const onFail = err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            return res.redirect('/');
        };

        keystone.session.signin(String(user._id), req, res, onSuccess, onFail);
    }

    function createOrUpdateUser(user) {
        if (user) {

            const userData = {
                email: authUser.email,
                services: user.services || {}
            };

            userData.services[authUser.type] = {
                isConfigured: true,
                profileId: authUser.profileId,
                username: authUser.username,
                avatar: authUser.avatar,
                accessToken: authUser.accessToken,
                refreshToken: authUser.refreshToken
            };

            user.set(userData);

            user.save((err, user) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                return doSignIn(user);
            });

        } else {

            const userData = {
                name: {
                    first: authUser.name.first,
                    last: authUser.name.last
                },
                email: authUser.email,
                password: Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8),
                services: {}
            };

            userData.services[authUser.type] = {
                isConfigured: true,
                profileId: authUser.profileId,
                username: authUser.username,
                avatar: authUser.avatar,
                accessToken: authUser.accessToken,
                refreshToken: authUser.refreshToken
            };

            const newUser = new User.model(userData);

            newUser.save((err, user) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                return doSignIn(user);
            });
        }
    }
};
```